# firebase Crashlytics not sending crash report on vending machine with android 7.1.2

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

i have my application on vending machine with Android 7.1.2 version i set firebase Crashlytics when i try throw `RuntimeException("Test Crash") // Force a crash` to test ANR crash on emulator it works fine and reflect on firebase console but on vending machine is not any specific reason ?
I also use Firebase Firestore it works fine in vending machine

Comment: Enable debug logging, then cause a test crash. These logs may give us hints into what could be happening: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable-debug-logging